# Android TextView's text coordinates on screen

Tags: android, textview, screen

Assuming that I have a TextView with text inside. Is it possible to get from that TextView some word's coordinates on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Here goes

```
TextView tv;
int[] coordinates = new int[2];

tv.getLocationOnScreen(coordinates);

Log.v("Coordinates of my TextView are: ", "Left(X) = "+coordinates[0]+" and Top(Y) = "+coordinates[1]);
```

Hope it helped))) Actually, it works for any view - not only a TV.

Comment: I wanted a particular word from that TV :-) But this answer could be a good start. I have to get letter's width in px and try to calculate distance from start of View. The problem is when there are more than one rows of text.

Comment: If I get what you mean try to use

<TextView
...whatever
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="ChooseYourOptionHere"
>

Comment: No, I don't want to make ellipsize :-) Just to replace part of text with image ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have resolved it. You have to use clickableSpan inside your TextView.
See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905486/how-get-coordinate-of-a-clickablespan-inside-a-textview) for more details, and tell me if you have any problem :)