# Get absolute position for a given offset on TextView (Android)

Tags: android, textview, position, character, offset

I have a TextView in which I want to place a solid color block over given words of the TextView, for example:

"This is a text string, I want to put a rectangle over this WORD" - so, "WORD" would have a rectangle with a solid color over it.

To do this, I am thinking about overriding the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method, in order to draw a block over the text. My only problem is to find an efficient way to get the absolute position of a given word or character.

Basically, I am looking for something that does the exact opposite of the [getOffsetForPosition(float x, float y) method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getOffsetForPosition%28float,%20float%29)

Comment: Is it a single line of text or multiline?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on this post: [How get coordinate of a ClickableSpan inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905486/how-get-coordinate-of-a-clickablespan-inside-a-textview), I managed to use this code in order to put a rectangle on top of the text:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    // Initialize global value
    TextView parentTextView = this;
    Rect parentTextViewRect = new Rect();

    // Find where the WORD is
    String targetWord = "WORD";
    int startOffsetOfClickedText = this.getText().toString().indexOf(targetWord);
    int endOffsetOfClickedText = startOffsetOfClickedText + targetWord.length();

    // Initialize values for the computing of clickedText position
    Layout textViewLayout = parentTextView.getLayout();

    double startXCoordinatesOfClickedText = textViewLayout.getPrimaryHorizontal((int)startOffsetOfClickedText);
    double endXCoordinatesOfClickedText = textViewLayout.getPrimaryHorizontal((int)endOffsetOfClickedText);

    // Get the rectangle of the clicked text
    int currentLineStartOffset = textViewLayout.getLineForOffset((int)startOffsetOfClickedText);
    int currentLineEndOffset = textViewLayout.getLineForOffset((int)endOffsetOfClickedText);
    boolean keywordIsInMultiLine = currentLineStartOffset != currentLineEndOffset;
    textViewLayout.getLineBounds(currentLineStartOffset, parentTextViewRect);

    // Update the rectangle position to his real position on screen
    int[] parentTextViewLocation = {0,0};
    parentTextView.getLocationOnScreen(parentTextViewLocation);

    double parentTextViewTopAndBottomOffset = (
        //parentTextViewLocation[1] - 
        parentTextView.getScrollY() + 
        parentTextView.getCompoundPaddingTop()
    );

    parentTextViewRect.top += parentTextViewTopAndBottomOffset;
    parentTextViewRect.bottom += parentTextViewTopAndBottomOffset;

    // In the case of multi line text, we have to choose what rectangle take
    if (keywordIsInMultiLine){

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
        int dyTop = parentTextViewRect.top;
        int dyBottom = screenHeight - parentTextViewRect.bottom;
        boolean onTop = dyTop > dyBottom;

        if (onTop){
            endXCoordinatesOfClickedText = textViewLayout.getLineRight(currentLineStartOffset);
        }
        else{
            parentTextViewRect = new Rect();
            textViewLayout.getLineBounds(currentLineEndOffset, parentTextViewRect);
            parentTextViewRect.top += parentTextViewTopAndBottomOffset;
            parentTextViewRect.bottom += parentTextViewTopAndBottomOffset;
            startXCoordinatesOfClickedText = textViewLayout.getLineLeft(currentLineEndOffset);
        }

    }

    parentTextViewRect.left += (
        parentTextViewLocation[0] +
        startXCoordinatesOfClickedText + 
        parentTextView.getCompoundPaddingLeft() - 
        parentTextView.getScrollX()
    );
    parentTextViewRect.right = (int) (
        parentTextViewRect.left + 
        endXCoordinatesOfClickedText - 
        startXCoordinatesOfClickedText
    );

    canvas.drawRect(parentTextViewRect, paint);
 }
```

Comment: I am not getting this, how do you use this..?? I mean If I select text, this code will be executed by it self?? Or we need to do something else?
I have created my custom text view and put this method in it. How will it be executed?

Comment: @NirPatel this code draws a rectangle on top of the `targetWord`, that's the algorithm input. If you use the code without any changes and write on you custom text view the `targetWord` (in this case "WORD"), a rectangle will be drawn on top of it. If you would like to place the rectangle on top of the user's selected text, then the `startOffsetOfClickedText `, and `endXCoordinatesOfClickedText ` would have to be calculated from whichever selection span is made by the user, however I believe this wont work well for multiple target words, since it only draws one rectangle.

Answer (score 5):

You can use spans for that.
First you create a spannable for your text, like this:

```
Spannable span = new SpannableString(text);
```

Then you put a span around the word that you want to highlight, somewhat like this:

```
span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), start, end, 
                     Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Unfortunately I don't know of an existing span that puts a border around a word.  I found UnderlineSpan, and also [BackgroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.html), perhaps these are also useful for you, or you can have a look at the code and see if you can create a BorderSpan based on one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing a rectangle over the WORD, you could simply replace its characters with an appropriate unicode symbol like U+25AE (▮ Black vertical rectangle).

So you'd get

> "This is a text string, I want to put a rectangle over this ▮▮▮▮"

If that is sufficient. See for example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Geometric_shapes) for a wast list of unicode symbols.

If you actually need to paint that black box you can do the following as long as your text is in a single line:

Calculate the width of the text part before 'WORD' as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794484/calculate-text-size-according-to-width-of-text-area) to find the left edge of the box and calcuate the width of 'WORD' using the same method to find the width of the box.

For a multiline text the explained method might also work but I think you'll have to do quite a lot of work here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, first of all. Since it is multiline, maybe I could use a technique where I would scan every line for the WORD, but I do not know if that is very efficient

Comment: Nah, that will not work well. You'd have to rebuild the text wrapping process of the TextView to find out whhat text is in which line.

Answer (score 0):

use `getLayout().getLineBottom` and `textpaint.measureText` to manually do the reverse calculation of `getOffsetForPosition`.

below is an example of using the calculated x,y for some textOffset to position the handle drawable when the textview gets clicked.

```
class TextViewCustom extends TextView{
    float lastX,lastY;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean ret = super.onTouchEvent(event);
        lastX=event.getX();
        lastY=event.getY();
        return ret;
    }

    BreakIterator boundary;
    Drawable handleLeft;
    private void init() {// call  it in constructors
        boundary = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
handleLeft=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_text_select_handle_left_mtrl_dark);
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int line = getLayout().getLineForVertical((int) lastY);
                int offset = getLayout().getOffsetForHorizontal(line, lastX);
                int wordEnd = boundary.following(offset);
                int wordStart = boundary.previous();
                CMN.Log(getText().subSequence(wordStart, wordEnd));

                int y = getLayout().getLineBottom(line);
                int trimA = getLayout().getLineStart(line);
                float x = getPaddingLeft()+getPaint().measureText(getText(), trimA, wordStart);


                x-=handleLeft.getIntrinsicWidth()*1.f*9/12;
                handleLeft.setBounds((int)x,y,(int)(x+handleLeft.getIntrinsicWidth()),y+handleLeft.getIntrinsicHeight());
                invalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(text, type);
        if(boundary!=null)
            boundary.setText(text.toString());
    }

}
```