# Get x,y Co-ordinate of text in android

Tags: android, canvas, view, coordinate-systems

[image]

**I want to get x,y co-ordinate array of displaying text on screen.**

**i have to get whole co-ordinate of "this string".**

I have 2 option to display text:

**1.Draw text in canvas->** when i am doing text on canvas using canvas.drawText().
then how to get all x,y co-ordinate to drawing text .i have to get top,bottom,left,right position.but can't get all co-ordinate of Drawing text.
please give me solution to getting whole x,y co-ordinate arraylist.

**2.Set Text in View(for ex,button,textview,edittext etc)->** i m doing settext() of view.but can't getting x,y co-ordinate array of whole displaying text.

I am draw this string using below code:

```
public class DrawCanvas extends View {
        public DrawCanvas (Context mContext) {
            super(mContext);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            clipBounds_canvas = canvas.getClipBounds();
            String str = "णमो अरिहंताणं";
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            int scaledSize = (int) getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.myFontSize);
            int fontSize = scaledSize;
            paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
            Log.e("tag", "canvas.getWidth()" + canvas.getWidth());
            int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
            int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2));
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawText(str, xPos, yPos, paint);
            canvas.drawPath(drawPath, paint);
        }


    }
```

**i want to get all x,y pixel when draw this string.....**

Comment: what's exactly your question?

Comment: @Blackbelt plz chk above 1st line

Comment: Are you trying to get x,y co-ordinate of each char of text?

Comment: yes i am trying to  get x,y co-ordinates,but not getting whole co-ordinates.just gettting only top,bottom,left ,right points

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11934366/4596556). It may help you.

Comment: you call `canvas.drawText()`, right? so you need to pass `x` and `y`, right? and now what x/y co-ordinate do you mean?

Comment: @pskink its mean to starting position of text.

Comment: i have no green idea what you mean... what actually do you want to achieve? maybe some picture describing your problem?

Comment: i see you have `xPos, yPos`, so what is the problem actually?